# Quasar dynamic slots and Typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I was creating a component that wraps a QInput, which passes everything down to it, but `vue-tsc` is complaining of the following:

```
 TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type '{ default: unknown; prepend: unknown; append: unknown; before: unknown; after: unknown; label: unknown; error: unknown; hint: unknown; counter: unknown; loading: unknown; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ default: unknown; prepend: unknown; append: unknown; before: unknown; after: unknown; label: unknown; error: unknown; hint: unknown; counter: unknown; loading: unknown; }'.

14         v-slot:[slot]="scope"
                  ~~~~~~
```

Component code:

```
<q-input
      borderless
      v-bind="$attrs"
      :model-value="props.modelValue"
    >
      <template
        v-for="(_, slot) in $slots"
        v-slot:[slot]="scope"
      >
        <slot
          :name="slot"
          v-bind="scope || {}"
        />
      </template>
    </q-input>
```

I was wondering if there is a workaround on this

Comment: Where is slot defined and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting my own answer from https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/discussions/14415#discussioncomment-3667451

You can utilize the `QInputSlots` type by casting `$slots` to `Readonly<QInputSlots>`.

> ```html
> <template>
>   <q-input
>     borderless
>     v-bind="$attrs"
>     :model-value="props.modelValue"
>   >
>     <template
>       v-for="(_, slot) in ($slots as Readonly<QInputSlots>)"
>       v-slot:[slot]="scope"
>     >
>       <slot
>         :name="slot"
>         v-bind="scope || {}"
>       />
>     </template>
>   </q-input>
> </template>
>
> <script setup lang="ts">
> import type { QInputSlots } from 'quasar';
>
> // ...
> </script>
>
> <script>
> export default {
>   inheritAttrs: false,
> }
> </script>
> ```
>
> However, you won't get auto-completion on slot names nor get type info
> on template scopes. I made a comment here to see if this is expected
> Volar behavior:
> https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/953#issuecomment-1250029543